# Verificar uma expressão regular com string em Java

Tags: java, regex

Estou precisando verificar se um determinado digito recuperado de uma expressão regular é igual ao meu digito do campo de entrada, estou usando o código abaixo mas não consigo fazer a verificação:

```
String digitoSenha = senha.substring(i, i + 1);
RegularExpression expressao = new RegularExpression(digitoSenha + " ou \\d|\\d ou " + digitoSenha);
```

> No caso ele retorna: 1 ou \d|\d ou 1

Tenho um elemento em tela que no `getText()` retornaria "4 ou 1", como verificar se o resultado da expressão está dentro do `getText()` ?

Comment: `new RegularExpression` não existe nativamente no Java. É uma classe do seu projeto? Se for poderia [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código dela também? De qualquer forma, para mim não está muito claro o que vc quer. Tem algum exemplo de strings que vc recebe e o que exatamente vc precisa verificar? Se for só ver se existe um dígito 1 ou 4 na string, acho que `indexOf` é mais fácil que regex...

Comment: Eu importo essa lib: import  org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegularExpression;

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem o que vc quer fazer, mas não bastaria fazer `if (expressao.matches(getText()) { etc... }`? Se entrar no `if` é porque o texto corresponde à regex. Outro detalhe: nunca usei essa lib, mas a menos que ela tenha algum recurso que a API nativa (`java.util.regex.Pattern`) não suporta - e vc precise usar este recurso - não vejo necessidade de usar uma lib.

Comment: Consegui fazer através do código abaixo:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= senha.length() - 1; i++) {
   String digitoSenha = senha.substring(i, i + 1);
   RegularExpression expressao = new RegularExpression(digitoSenha + " ou \\d|\\d ou " + digitoSenha);
   int botao = 0;
   for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {

    botao = botao + 1;
    String botaoTela = driver
      .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frmKey']/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/a[" + botao + "]")).getText();

    if (expressao.matches(botaoTela)) {
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frmKey']/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/a[" + botao + "]")).click();
     break;
    }
   }
   ;